# random display of data in database that display in textview

Tags: android, database-connection

PLEASE HELP, For a Quiz apps, my problem is i can't random the display data from my database to text view. And this is my code:

How can I fix it, Thanks :)

```
      private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.hahaha);

            mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
            mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
            mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();

            mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Highly weathered soil of the tropics belong to the Soil Order");
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert("The best soil texture class for growing irrigated lowland rice is ");
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Which of the following crops can tolerate very strongly acidic soil conditions");
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Acid sulfate soils are often found in areas where the parent material of the soil is derived from ");
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Soil microorganisms which are capable of deriving energy for life processes only from the decomposition of organic compounds and incapable of using inorganic compounds as sole sources of energy are known as");

            final TextView TextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                TextView.setText(mySQLiteAdapter.getRandomQuestion());
                }

            });

            mySQLiteAdapter.close();

            /*
             *  Open the same SQLite database
             *  and read all it's content.
             */
            mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
            mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
            String contentRead = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
            mySQLiteAdapter.close();

            TextView.setText(contentRead);

        }
```

For SQLITE ADAPTER

```
public class SQLiteAdapter {

 public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
 public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
 public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "Content";

 //create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
 private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
  "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
  + KEY_CONTENT + " text not null);";

 private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

 private Context context;

 public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
  context = c;
 }

 public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
  sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
  sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
  return this; 
 }

 public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
  sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
  sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this; 
 }

 public void close(){
  sqLiteHelper.close();
 }

 public long insert(String content){

  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
  contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
  return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
 }

 public int deleteAll(){
  return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
 }

 public String queueAll(){
  String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_CONTENT};
  Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, 
    null, null, null, null, null);
  String result = "";

  int index_CONTENT = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT);
  for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !(cursor.isAfterLast()); cursor.moveToNext()){
   result = result + cursor.getString(index_CONTENT) + "\n";
  }

  return result;
 }

 public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
    CursorFactory factory, int version) {
   super(context, name, factory, version);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

 }

public CharSequence getRandomQuestion() {
    Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",
            new String[] { KEY_CONTENT }, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(c.moveToFirst())
      return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT));
    else 
      return "nothing";
}

}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: The problem is all the text(question) is displayed, I want that every time i click the button the next question appeared and its display in random order. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because

```
TextView.setText(contentRead);
```

this will make all the date into the textview. Please remove the line

Also, you want to display only the random questions. So these lines are not necessary.

```
/*mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
String contentRead = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
mySQLiteAdapter.close();
TextView.setText(contentRead);*/
```

I seriously advise you to change your TextView name. Because TextView is a reserved word in android.

```
final TextView TextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Please give different name as

```
final TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

and make your Button's onclick like below to work

```
mySQLiteAdapter.close();// close previously opened
public void onClick(View v)
{
mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
textview.setText(mySQLiteAdapter.getRandomQuestion());
mySQLiteAdapter.close();
}
```

Comment: What happened now? whether it ll display one question or not?

Comment: It display one question :) but when i click the button the app stop :(

Comment: It shows one question only and every time i click the button the apps stopped :'(